# Open AI Gym: Ant not rendering

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have been unable to render the ant using the OpenAI gym framework.
Here is my code:

```py
import gymnasium as gym

env = gym.make("Ant-v4")

# Reset the environment to start a new episode
observation = env.reset()

for _ in range(1000):
    # Render the environment
    env.render()

    # Take a random action
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)

    if done:
        # Reset the environment if the episode is done
        observation = env.reset()

# Close the environment
env.close()
```

And this is the error that I get `raise AttributeError( AttributeError: Unexpected mode: None, expected modes: human, rgb_array, or depth_array`

I have tried to use a virtual environment and I have installed all the libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a render mode. So if you want to render this environment, you would use:

```
env = gym.make("Ant-v4", render_mode='human')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know why I would now be getting the error: AttributeError: 'mujoco._structs.MjData' object has no attribute 'solver_iter'. Did you mean: 'solver_niter'?

Comment: If I have to guess, you would have to look into the versions of packages you use. Make sure that if you follow a tutorial, you use the exact same versions as described, because packages may change, especially with `gym` there are major differences between versions